# Run Another Program in Linux from a C++ Program

Tags: c++, linux, unix, terminal

Okay so my question is this. Say I have a simple C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   cout << "Hello World" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Now say I have this program that I would like to run in my program, call it prog. Running this in the terminal could be done by:

```
./prog
```

Is there a way to just do this from my simple C++ program? For instance

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   ./prog ??
   cout << "Hello World" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Any feedback would be very much obliged.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c

Comment: @hopia, not a duplicate. What you pointed to is a question about advanced uses of `system()`; this poster just needed to know about the function’s existence.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You want the `system()` library call; see [system(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system).  For example:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
   std::system("./prog");
   return 0;
}
```

The exact command string will be system-dependent, of course.

Comment: How can I get the pid of the new proc?

Comment: @Gil404: PID is a Unix concept and not all OSes have it. If you need that, use the POSIX `fork` and `exec`, or your operating system’s equivalent.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use popen

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        FILE *handle = popen("./prog", "r");

        if (handle == NULL) {
                return 1;
        }

        char buf[64];
        size_t readn;
        while ((readn = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), handle)) > 0) {
                fwrite(buf, 1, readn, stdout);
        }

        pclose(handle);

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could us the system command:

```
system("./prog");
```

Answer (score 4):

Try [system(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) :

```
system("./prog");
```

Comment: In <cstdlib>.  And maybe slap an std:: on that system.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a system call like this:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/

Careful if you use user input as a parameter, its a good way to have some unintended consequences. Scrub everything!

Generally, system calls can be construed as bad form.