# Running a Linux Executable from C/C++ Executable Without Use of system() or system() Wrappers

Tags: c++, c, linux, execution

I am looking for a way to execute a Linux executable from a separate Linux Executable that was compiled from C or C++. However, I have looked at numerous Stack Overflow posts which all direct the user asking to use the `system()` function or a wrapper of the system function and I do not want a program that relies on the shell, because it could easily fall apart if it was transferred to a different operating system with a different shell.

In the post [How do I execute an external program within C in Linux with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237482/how-do-i-execute-external-program-within-c-code-in-linux-with-arguments), the second answer states that `execve()` is a wrapper for the `system()` function, and this makes me wary of the other functions in the `exec()` family.

I have also looked at the following articles:

- [How do you write a C program to execute another program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460421/how-do-you-write-a-c-program-to-execute-another-program)
- http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/168287/
- [Run Another Program in Linux from a C++ Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120596/run-another-program-in-linux-from-a-c-program)

All help is appreciated!

Comment: "*execve() is a wrapper for the system function*". It's not the case. It's the other way around - `system` is a wrapper for `execve`. The [system manaul](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) gives that info: "*The system() library function uses fork(2) to create a child process that executes the shell command specified in command using execl(3)*". So using the `exec` functions might actually be what you need?

Comment: `system` is really, really dumb. Many consider it to be a security hole because of how stupid it is.

Comment: The second answer doesn't say that `execve()` is a wrapper for the `system` function. It says `system` uses `exec*` functions.

Comment: If you're worried about portability, then `system()` is the portable way to do the job; it is required by the Standard C library so, for most practical purposes, it will be available anywhere C is available.  However, there are some security risks associated with it, and it doesn't necessarily handle all the scenarios you want.  In that case, you almost invariably end up using `fork()` and the `exec()` family of functions, possibly with `pipe()` and `dup2()`, or maybe some more esoteric functions for handling pseudo-terminals (aka pseudo-ttys or ptys).

Comment: On POSIX systems, an alternative to the `fork()` and `exec*()` functions is the [`posix_spawn()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html)
function and its relatives (findable from https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`execve()` is not a wrapper for `system()`; it is a wrapper for the `execve` syscall itself.

`execve()` *replaces* the current process, so you’ll probably need to `fork()` and then execute `execve()` in the child process, thereby emulating the behaviour of `system()`.

Comment: when the current process is replaced, and the program executed by `execve()` finishes, is control return to the previous process, or is the process eliminated entirely?

Comment: @ShortsKing, on success, `execve()` does not return.  The binary executing in the calling process is completely replaced by the one designated by `execve()`'s arguments.  Note also that it is more common to use one of the various other [exec-family functions](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) than to use `execve()` directly.

Comment: System call numbers are only meaningful for a specific OS _and architecture_ and the only time you should have to worry about the actual numbers is when you're adding new system calls to the kernel.  Saying (#11) just confuses people.  Please edit that out.

Comment: @zwol You're right; of course they're unhelpful. Thanks for pointing that out. I've been writing a lot of assembly recently, so the first thing I thought of when I saw `execve()` was "11".

Comment: Even in assembly you ought to be able to use the `SYS_*` constants from `sys/syscall.h`, can't you?

Comment: @zwol Yes, I can. I'm just learning, though, so it helps me to know the numbers so I can better understand the assembled binary.